# Configuring BNO details in a node in corda

Tags: blockchain, corda

So if a node joins multiple business networks,where is it storing the info regrading the business network which it is a participant of?Is it really storing or configuring details like party object of the BNO?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple business networks could run within the same corda network say insurance network, supply chain network etc. The nodes in the network are free to install cordapps and transact with other nodes in the network. Thus business network in this context is a logical construct.

Take a look at the diagram in the below link which shows how different nodes could choose to install cordapps and be part of different business networks while being within a single corda network.
https://solutions.corda.net/business-networks/interoperability.html

There is no configuration details stored for these business network but each business network could have their own governance and operations structure.

Comment: Thanks!!..Then why do we add configuration file for bno and member where bno config file contain the accepted notary and member config contain whitelist of accepted bno?

Comment: Which configuration file are you talking about? Could you share a link where you refer this?

Comment: https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/memberships-management. Please check the configuration in read me

Comment: These are bno-cordapp configs which can be provided when one installs the bno cordapps. This is similar to configs for any general cordapps. Nothing specific to the corda node. These specific cordapps help BNO to manager business networks effectively.